# How to create a new partition on a hard disk?

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, fdisk

How do I create a new partition on a hard disk, from the terminal? I've been reading the `man` pages for `fdisk` and `mkfs`, but they're confusing. I need to know how to create a new partition on a blank drive, as well as on a drive that already has partitions. Some colleagues told me the latter isn't possible and I need to format; is that accurate?

Comment: Are GUI applications allowed?

Comment: No i want to do it from the command prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install [GNU parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/index.shtml) (`libparted`), you get an extra command line progam `parted`.

> GNU Parted manipulates partition
>   tables. This is useful for creating
>   space for new operating systems,
>   reorganizing disk usage, copying data
>   on hard disks and disk imaging. The
>   package contains a library, libparted,
>   as well as well as a command-line
>   frontend, parted, which can also be
>   used in scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i would like to know more about using fdisk and mkfs in getting this achieved.

Comment: I'd like to add that there is a very good GUI called gparted for libparted (I know GUI's not allowed but it is still worth mentioning).

Answer (score 1):

- Backup every piece of data you can't afford to lose and don't do this on a mission-critical server.
- `umount` the partition you want to split into two or more parts.
- Use `resize2fs` to free up the desired amount of space at the end of partition.
- Launch `fdisk`.

Unfortunately, this tool doesn't have an option to change the size of partition.  You'll need to delete it first and then create the desired new partitions on the unallocated space left from it.

First re-create the partition you've just deleted with lower amount of allocated space.  Be sure to specify size enough to hold your resized filesystem.  Allocate the rest of unused space as you see fit.

The `fdisk` tool doesn't touch your partition table unless you specifically say it to do so.  In case of mess up, just terminate it with `^C` and start over.

- Now that you have you new partitions setup, use an appropriate `mkfs` command to create new filesystems.  Don't run `mkfs` on the original partition number -- only on the new ones!
- Take extra care at every step as you risk the need start over in case of mistyped command.

Comment: can you give me the commands i should use for achieving the same?

Comment: @Sen: sorry, no.  You'll have to figure it out.  Feel free to ask separate questions, specific to the command you'll trying to learn about.  Like 'How do I use resize2fs?'